# How to add vertical scroll bars to view in android?

Tags: android, scrollbar

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture_avatar"
        android:layout_width="90dp" 
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#bdbdbd"
        android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/picture_avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture_avatar"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_fullname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture_avatar"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_fullname"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_email"
        android:autoLink="phone" 
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_website"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_phone"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_bio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_website"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_lastactive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_bio"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_datejoined"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_lastactive"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_dateleft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_datejoined"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="CloseActivity"
            android:text="@+string/back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="GoToEditProfile"
            android:text="@+string/edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I add vertical scroll bars, that only show if the content is too long?

I tried wrapping it with

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

But the bottom textviews and buttons were overlapping...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way will be to wrap up your entire layout with scrollview.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

...YOUR PREVIOUS LAYOUT HERE...
....

</ScrollView>
```

Just remember to remove the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on your relative layout. you only need it once.

With that, your layout will support scrolling when the content is too long.

Answer (score 1):

***Scrollview*** can have only one child element, like a ***vertical linearlayout*** for instance. Then your other views will be child elements of the ***linearlayout***.

Comment: please provide a complete answer by showing some snippet explaining your solution. That'll help the other users as well in the community.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a scrollview, then add a vertical layout in that scrollview. After that, you can add textview, button or anything you want.

```
           <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/act_test_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must create a scrollview, then add a vertical layout in that scrollview. After that, you can add textview, button or anything you want.